# Correctly making use of TPL/Tasks and understand flow

Tags: c#, wpf

Complete beginner with TPL/Asynchonrous programming, but I'm trying to get through it for something i'm working on.

I have a task that calls a method which should continue to run until the 'Address' is not null.
Once Address has some non-null value, ideally i'd like to create a new instance of a window, and 
make it visible to the user.

I am able to get the task to run as I want it to (every 5 seconds), but I can't figure out how
I am able to show a new window to the user once this action has completed, and then should no 'confirmation' be given on that form restart the 'Find' process.

I'm particularly confused by the program flow using tasks thus far, but what i'm trying to achieve/the code I've got so far is below:

Goals:

- Perform FindTheAddress until _profile.Address is no longer null
- Create an instance of and make visible some WPF window
- Once the window loads the user must confirm that the Address is correct
- Failing to confirm we begin 'FindAddress' again to find an alternative match.

My code simplified below for the sake of attempting to explain:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SomeClass.SomeMethod(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), ts1.Token));
```

Method:

```
public async void FindAddress(TimeSpan interval, CancellationToken token)
{
    while (_profile.Address == null)
    {     
            //FindTheAddress in reality makes an API request (EWS)
            _profile.Address = FindTheAddress();

            if (interval <= TimeSpan.Zero) return;
            await Task.Delay(interval, token);
    }
  //This throws some nasty STA issue I don't really understand.
  (new SomeWindow()).Activate();
}
```

Any help / clarification appreciated on the subject, I've tried going through the MSDN documentation but I didn't find them very digestable.

Comment: You should not be starting a new `Task` to run the `FindAddress()` method. Just call it from your UI thread (e.g. in response to a button `Click` event handler, etc.). Post a _complete_ code example, if you want an answer that actually explains how to adjust your code so that it's correct. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I had initially done so, but my UI was unresponsive every 5 seconds as a consequence.  What 'FindAddress' really does in my application is run in the background and look for 'Addresses', once it finds one I am aiming to show a new Window -> and await some confirmation for x amount of time -> after x amount of time has passed -> resume finding addresses.

Comment: No, not with the code you posted here. Not unless the parameterless `FindTheAddress()` method itself takes 5 seconds for each call. This is why you need to post a _complete_ code example.

Comment: This code is begging to be reactive. See [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx). I'd imagine it would be something like this: `addressChanges.Throttle(interval).Select(FindTheAddress).Switch().Subscribe(ShowWindow)`.

Comment: I'd never heard of Reactive Extensions, i'll take a look thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the need for a background thread at all here, unless `FindTheAddress` is CPU-intensive (and I can't imagine it would be).

So, you can just use regular `async`/`await` for this. You should [avoid `async void`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) (as I describe in my MSDN article). This means your work method would look like this:

```
public async Task FindAddressAsync(TimeSpan interval, CancellationToken token)
{
  while (_profile.Address == null)
  {     
    _profile.Address = FindTheAddress();

    if (interval <= TimeSpan.Zero) return;
    await Task.Delay(interval, token);
  }
}
```

Then, whatever starts off this process (button click, etc) can just use `await` as such:

```
await FindAddressAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), ts1.Token);
(new SomeWindow()).Activate();
```

Comment: FindAddress in the actual context performs a Exchange Web Services API call and searches for the Address, sorry I should have probably mentioned that in the initial question.

Answer (score 1):

Without a complete code example, it's really not clear what's needed here. But the following version of your `FindAddress(TimeSpan, CancellationToken)` method has nothing in it that would block, and so is guaranteed to work even if you call it from the UI thread (as you should):

```
public async Task FindAddress(TimeSpan interval, CancellationToken token)
{
    while ((_profile.Address = await Task.Run(() => FindTheAddress())) == null)
    {     
            if (interval <= TimeSpan.Zero) return;
            await Task.Delay(interval, token);
    }
  //This throws some nasty STA issue I don't really understand.
  (new SomeWindow()).Activate();
}
```

This ensures that even if the parameterless `FindTheAddress()` method is time-consuming (e.g. takes five seconds to return), it won't block the UI thread. That operation will be run in a different thread, with the continuation automatically executed back in the UI thread.

Note that I have also adjust the code so that it won't fail needlessly (i.e. if the delay is zero but the first call succeeds), and so that it won't add an unnecessary delay (i.e. by calling `Delay()` even once the method returns a non-null value).